# Scan Wirelessly

Tags: wireless-networking, osx-yosemite, scanning

How can I Scan from a Brother MFC-J625DW wirelessly to Mac !0.10.5 OS X Yosemite.
I can print with no problem and have trialed Vue Scan which worked effortlessly
but I cannot use OS X Yosemite yet all the blurbs say it has the capacity.
How do you turn it on?

Comment: Have you read the release notes about Mac compatibility and possible workarounds? http://www.hamrick.com/vuescan/vuescan.htm#macosx

Comment: There is a scan software for Mac called Exactscan that supports a few Brother document scanners. You could use the 14-days trial to test your model.